# cleaning multiple documents and saving them to one book with a loop in Pandas

Tags: python, loops, pandas, xlsx

I have a list of almost 30 xlsx files of the same format. I have a working data cleaning code for and I want to clean them all and save them on individual sheets in a single book. I figured a loop would be best to do the job, but something is missing. I have seen some functions that save multiple sheets to a work book, but I am hoping to read_excel, clean data frame, save to sheet and delete dataframe. What is happening is that it only returns the final sheet on the list in the new excel document.

```
BOX = [
"aa1",
"aa2",
"aa3"]

for B in BOX:

    filename = B+".xls"

    #create data frame
    BDF = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Projects\BOXES\\' + filename)
    #clean data frame
    BDF = BDF.dropna(how="all")
    BDF['Total Cost'] = BDF['Total Cost'].str.replace('.', '')
    BDF.columns = ['LVL', 'PN', 'Leadtime', 'Description', 'Ext QTY']
    BDF.PN = BDF.PN.str.strip()

    sheetname=B
    #save to sheet
    with pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Projects\BOXES\BOXED.xlsx') as writer:
        BDF.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=B, index=False)
    #delete data frame before repeating 
    del(BDF)
    del(B)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the `with` outside the loop, since it automatically opens and closes the file in each `for` loop. The following should work:

```
BOX = [
"aa1",
"aa2",
"aa3"]

with pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Projects\BOXES\BOXED.xlsx') as writer:

    for B in BOX:

        filename = B+".xls"

        #create data frame
        BDF = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Projects\BOXES\\' + filename)
        #clean data frame
        BDF = BDF.dropna(how="all")
        BDF['Total Cost'] = BDF['Total Cost'].str.replace('.', '')
        BDF.columns = ['LVL', 'PN', 'Leadtime', 'Description', 'Ext QTY']
        BDF.PN = BDF.PN.str.strip()

        sheetname=B
        #save to sheet
        BDF.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=B, index=False)
        #delete data frame before repeating 
        del(BDF)
        del(B)
```

Comment: Thanks, this did it!

Comment: you're welcome. Don't forget to upvote the answer if it works for you!

Comment: One more question, by having 'with' inside the loop what was it doing? I'm still not sure I understand what was happening before the fix.

Comment: You were just open write and close the file at each loop, that's why at the end you got only the last sheet of excel file, as a result of the last for loop.